# Can a continuous bounded function $u:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ be approximated by linear combinations of exponential?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

When I learned WLLN and Bernstein polynomial I saw this queation. It is known that a continuous function on the interval [0, 1] can be approximated by Bernstein polynomial, using Bernoulli trials and WLLN.[Proof on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Approximating_continuous_functions)

So I try to solve my question using Poisson random variable, but it seems hard.

Comment: "Approximated" how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a linear combination of exponential functions,
$$ f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i e^{b_ix} $$
where without loss of generality we shall assume that all $a_i\ne 0$ and the $b_i$ are distinct.

If any of the $b_i$s is positive, then for large $x$, $f(x)$ is dominated by the term with the *largest* $b_i$, and therefore $f(x)\to \infty$ or $f(x)\to-\infty$ depending on the sign of the corresponding $a_i$.

On the other hand if every $b_i\le 0$, then $f(x)$ has a finite limit for $x\to\infty$.

These two facts combine to show that, for example, $\sin x$ cannot be approached **uniformly** by combinations of exponentials.

---

On the other hand, we can approach any continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ **pointwise** by such combinantions -- and for this it doesn't even need to be bounded.

To see this, note that a continuous function of $x\in[0,\infty)$ is also a continuous function of $e^{x}\in [1,\infty)$ -- and thanks to the Weierstrass approximation theorem we can approximate that uniformly on any $[1,N]$ by a combination of powers of $e^{x}$, which is to say, by a combination of terms of the form $a_ne^{nx}$.

If choose each $f_N$ to be a combination of exponentials that approximates $f$ to within $\frac1N$ for $e^x\in [1,N]$, then $\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(x)=f(x)$ everywhere in $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Why are the $a_i$ distinct? I think you mean the $b_i$ are distinct and the $a_i$ are nonzero.

Comment: @Ian, whoops yes.

Comment: @Henning Makholm, thanks a lot! You mean that if $lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists finite, then all $b_i\leq0$ and $f(x)$ can be approached uniformly.

Comment: @Z.f.y: I didn't write that, but it is true.